# Matlab: extrac i_th pixel of all images stored in a cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have an `image_data` cell array contains 400 images:

```
image_data = {img1, img2, ... img400}
```

each image, such as `img1`, is a `128 x 128` array of pixel values:

```
img1 = [0.2, 0.5, .....]
```

I want to get all the i_th pixel of all images stored in `image_data`, but **not using a for-loop**.

For Example:

```
image_data = {img1, img2, img3}
img1 = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
img2 = [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
img3 = [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
```

I want to calculate the variance the following quickly:

```
var([img1(1),img2(1),img3(1)]) = var([0.1,0.4,0.7]) 
var([img1(2),img2(2),img3(2)]) = var([0.2,0.5,0.8]) 
var([img1(3),img2(3),img3(3)]) = var([0.3,0.6,0.9])
```

Try to avoid using a loop, because it is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to convert that unwieldy cell array into a 3-dimensional array by concatenating the images along the 3rd dimension:

```
image_array = cat(3, image_data{:});
```

Now, all we have to do is use a subscript to get the vector of the *ith* pixel from every image into a vector and pass that to `var`:

```
pixel_var = var(image_array(1,1,:));  % var for pixel 1
```

Or just do the whole image at once and index into the result:

```
image_var = var(image_array, 0, 3);   % take var along 3rd dimension
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @beaker's solution.

```
img1 = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3];
img2 = [0.4, 0.5, 0.6];
img3 = [0.7, 0.8, 0.9];
image_data = {img1, img2, img3};


image_array = cat(1, image_data{:}) % concatinate the cell array to 2-d array
pix_array = var(image_array,0,1) % apply var() to all columns
```

I got this:

```
image_array =

    0.1000    0.2000    0.3000
    0.4000    0.5000    0.6000
    0.7000    0.8000    0.9000


pix_array =

    0.0900    0.0900    0.0900
```